# Web Service Call Via CXF Gives Null Parameters

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have two code projects both using CXF to use web services.  When I make a call from project A to project B, the method I am calling receives null parameters.  I've turned on logging and the inbound message does indeed contain the correct parameters.  I have also tried calling my service from SoapUI (a webservice testing tool). This passes over the parameters as I expect. Anyone have any ideas what's going wrong?

The service interface:

```
@WebService
public interface IShortlistService {

  public IShortlist createOrUpdateShortlist(@WebParam(name = "sessionId") String sessionId,
      @WebParam(name = "datastoreInstance") String datastoreInstance,
      @WebParam(name = "datastoreRecordId") String datastoreRecordId);
}
```

The service impl:

```
@Name("shortlistService")
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.oobjects.shortlist.service.IShortlistService", serviceName = "ShortlistService")
@Features(features = "org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature")
@Transactional
public class ShortlistService implements IShortlistService {
  public IShortlist createOrUpdateShortlist(String sessionId, String datastoreInstance,
      String datastoreRecordId) {
    // At this point all inputs are null
  }
}
```

Logging for inbound message that proves it's OK:

```
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {cache-control=[no-cache], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], connection=[keep-alive], host=[mypc.mycompany.com:8080], content-length=[391], SOAPAction=[""], user-agent=[Apache CXF 2.2.5], Accept=[*/*], pragma=[no-cache]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns1:createOrUpdateShortlist xmlns:ns1="http://service.shortlist.mycompany.com/"><sessionId>854a48b5-922f-4081-9c76-b6d08b58a341</sessionId><datastoreInstance>http://mypc.mycompany.com:8080/shortlist-app/services/ShortlistService</datastoreInstance></ns1:createOrUpdateShortlist></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
```

The versions of CXF are the same (2.2.5).  I can't think what else to check!

Some requested information...

- @Name is a Seam annotation
- Configured programmatically
- Aegis databinding (JAXWS doesn't like interfaces)

Comment: How are you configuring? Which data binding? what is @Name?

Comment: I've added the info you requested at the end.

Comment: Simple front end, then? It won't respect those @WebService annotations.

I'm afraid that this would work better on cxf-users. This isn't a simple 'I can answer your question' sort of thing, it's going to be an extended diagnostic exercise.

Comment: Sad that the answer to this problem isn't posted here as I have the same problem just now.

Comment: @Tim I don't think I ever got to the cause but I believe it was something to do with the use of the @WebParam annotations.  The recieving side was expecting results with set names and those weren't what I had in the @WebParam annotation, it was expecting arg0, arg1 etc.  When I removed the @WebParam I believe it worked.

Comment: It had nothing to do with the @WebParam annotion. I wrote the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lee Theobald ... there's nothing obvious in your posted question that reveals why it isn't working for you. In this case, the 'answer,' such as it is, is to request assistance on "CXF Users" , and, if necessary, open a JIRA. Playing 20 questions in the question comments isn't very efficient, and there are a lot more CXF-expert eyeballs on that list than here at this point. We could bring an amended question and answer back over here once the mystery is revealed.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  Just knowing that I've not made an obvious mistake is a something good though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem resolved as an error. The guy whose interface I was using didn't update from the repository before deploying his service, and as something had changed on his part (a throws clause was removed) that he checked in but didn't deploy, I used the fresher version from the repository. His version of the interface threw an exception, but my version of the interface didn't say so. So:

**This error can occur if service provider and service client use a slightly different interface.**

Comment: Oh I answered this question as I had the same issue and found it out. Somehow thought I posed the question in the first place.