# Java webservices: empty arrays

Tags: java, data-binding, apache-axis, axis, cxf

What is the right way to return empty arrays from webservices in Java? I need that empty arrays sholdn't be nulls on client. If I use Apache CXF or Axis 2 with default databinding I receive null insted of empty arrays. 
If I use CXF and AegisDatabinding -- problem is solved, but when I calling this webservice from Axis 2 client -- I receive null parameters on server (like in this question [Web Service Call Via CXF Gives Null Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087465/web-service-call-via-cxf-gives-null-parameters)).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed a couple times on the CXF lists and JIRA:

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-2627-still-failign-in-2-2-9-td1247184.html#a1247184

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2978

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2627

The only way is to write custom wrapper objects that add the  @XmlElementWrapper annotation.

Comment: I marked getter with @XmlElementWrapper(nillable = true) and received array with one not initialized element insted of empty array. Reсeive this is more strange than receive null :)